# fast folder size calculation in Python on Windows

Tags: python, windows, size, directory

I am looking for a fast way to calculate the size of a folder in Python on Windows. This is what I have so far:

```
def get_dir_size(path):
  total_size = 0
  if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    try:
      items = win32file.FindFilesW(path + '\\*')
    except Exception, err:
      return 0

    # Add the size or perform recursion on folders.
    for item in items:
      attr = item[0]
      name = item[-2]
      size = item[5]

      if (attr & win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) and \
         not (attr & win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM):  # skip system dirs
        if name not in DIR_EXCLUDES:
          total_size += get_dir_size("%s\\%s" % (path, name))

      total_size += size

  return total_size
```

This is not good enough when size of folder is over 100G. Any ideas how to improve it?

On a fast machine (2Ghz+ - 5G of RAM), it took 72 seconds to go over 422GB in 226,001 files and 12,043 folders. It takes 40 seconds using the explorer properties option.

I know I am being a bit greedy but I am hoping for a better solution.

Laurent Luce

Comment: What happens when the folder size is over 100G?  Do you get a wrong answer, does it fail completely, does it just take too long, or what?

Comment: On a fast machine (2Ghz+ - 5M of RAM), it took 72 seconds to go over 422GB in 226,001 files and 12,043 folders. I know I am being a bit greedy but I am hoping for a better solution.

Comment: @Laurent, best edit your question to include those stats.  That's critical to helping people answer effectively.  You might also report on the time to use Explorer's Properties dialog and the "du" utility (e.g. from Unxutils) for comparison.

Comment: is `dir /s > NUL` a lot faster on the same folder?

Comment: That sounds pretty much like what I'd expect for such a huge amount of files. What makes you think it can be done faster? Is Windows's built-in file size counter significantly faster?

Comment: 5M of RAM?  5MB?  You *do* mean 5G, right? ;-)

Comment: I added stats to the initial question. It is 5G of RAM, yes, sorry.

Comment: Windows built-in size counter is a bit faster but not much. I guess we reached the best implementation in Python then.

Comment: Is DIR_EXCLUDES just `['.', '..']` or does it include other stuff?  Also, do you get the same time results the second time you run it?  Windows XP and beyond do some pretty freaky caching of filesystem info, and it can really affect benchmark results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick profiling of your code suggests that over 90% of the time is consumed in the `FindFilesW()` call alone.  This means any improvements by tweaking the Python code would be minor.

Tiny tweaks (if you were to stick with FindFilesW) could include ensuring DIR_EXCLUDES is a set instead of a list, avoiding the repeated lookups on other modules, and indexing into item[] lazily, as well as moving the sys.platform check outside.  This incorporates these changes and others, **but it won't give more than a 1-2% speedup**.

```
DIR_EXCLUDES = set(['.', '..'])
MASK = win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY | win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM
REQUIRED = win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY
FindFilesW = win32file.FindFilesW

def get_dir_size(path):
    total_size = 0
    try:
        items = FindFilesW(path + r'\*')
    except pywintypes.error, ex:
        return total_size

    for item in items:
        total_size += item[5]
        if (item[0] & MASK == REQUIRED):
            name = item[8]
            if name not in DIR_EXCLUDES:
                total_size += get_dir_size(path + '\\' + name)

    return total_size
```

The only *significant* speedup would come from using a different API, or a different technique.  You mentioned in a comment doing this in the background, so you could structure it to do an incremental update using one of the packages for monitoring changes in folders.  Possibly the [FindFirstChangeNotification API](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html) or something like it.  You could set up to monitor the entire tree, or depending on how that routine works (I haven't used it) you might be better off registering multiple requests on various subsets of the full tree, if that reduces the amount of searching you have to do (when notified) to figure out what actually changed and what size it is now.

**Edit:** I asked in a comment whether you were taking into account the heavy filesystem metadata caching that Windows XP and later do.  I just checked performance of your code (and mine) against Windows itself, selecting all items in my C:\ folder and hitting Alt-Enter to bring up the properties window.  After doing this once (using your code) and getting a 40s elapsed time, I now get 20s elapsed from *both methods*.  In other words, **your code is actually just as fast as Windows itself**, at least on my machine.

Comment: Thanks for this enhanced version even if the gain is small. It seems that we a reached a limit so we are going to run our process in background and keep the folders size list up to date using the change notification Windows supports. Same idea as you are suggesting.

Comment: This function will not give the proper folder size for large files.
You must use both high order and low order size, explained here by user Lindley:
http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?465171-high-or-low-order-DWORD
So the line that add to total_size should be
total_size += float( item[4] * ( 2 ** 32 ) + item[5] )

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use a recursive algorithm if you use os.walk. [Please check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335078/whats-the-best-way-to-get-the-size-of-a-folder-and-all-the-files-inside-from-pyt).

You should time both approaches, but this is supposed to be much faster:

```
import os

def get_dir_size(root):
    size = 0
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
        for f in files:
            size +=  os.path.getsize( os.path.join( path, f ) )
    return size
```

Comment: The approach you are proposing takes 139 seconds instead of 72 seconds. We were using that one before and it is much slower.

Comment: So, you already got a speedup of almost 100%, and you're still no satisfied?  Greedy basterd!  ;-) ;-)

Comment: Is it possible that the approach that I proposed run slower because it's going through all the files while yours is skipping sytems dirs and folders in the list DIR_EXCLUDES?

Comment: Instead of using for loops, you could try map and reduce. For thousands of files the performance benefit could be significant.

Comment: @jbochi, 90%+ of the time consumed is in accessing the filesystem, so it's unlikely much improvement could be seen using things like map().

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a Windows box to test on at the moment, but the documentation states that
`win32file.FindFilesIterator` is "similar to `win32file.FindFiles`, but avoid the creation of the list for huge directories".  Does that help?

Comment: It didn't here.  Slightly slower, in fact, which perhaps isn't too surprising considering that the list is built in C code and there should be less overhead scanning a list than using an iterator.

Answer (score 1):

It's a whopper of a directory tree.  As others have said, I'm not sure you can speed it up... not like that, cold w/o data.  And that means...

If you can *cache* data, somehow (not sure what the actual implication is), then you could speed things up (I think... as always, measure, measure, measure).

I don't think I have to tell you how to do caching, I guess, you seem like a knowledgeable person.  And I wouldn't know off the cuff for Windows anyway. ;-)

Comment: The approach we are going to take is compute the folders size in the background in our app so they are ready when the users asked for them.

Answer (score 1):

This jumps out at me:

```
try:
  items = win32file.FindFilesW(path + '\\*')
except Exception, err:
  return 0
```

Exception handling can add significant time to your algorithm.  If you can specify the path differently, in a way that you always know is safe, and thus prevent the need to capture exceptions (eg, checking first to see if the given path is a folder before finding files in that folder), you may find a significant speedup.

Comment: Actually, try/except blocks in Python (contrary to experience from some other languages) are very cheap when exceptions are not raised, and in any case that code is there to catch problems that could not be determined in advance (such as "access denied" on certain items) so it can't really be avoided.

Comment: You can never check everything before executing an operation in the file system. Unless file systems start supporting transactions (like in SQL) someone can delete the directory just a nanosecond after you checked it's there and another nanosecond before you start to use it! Never skip error/exception handling for file system operations!

Answer (score 0):

```
# Size of File Folder/Directory in MBytes

import os

# pick a folder you have ...
folder = 'D:\\zz1'
folder_size = 0
for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk(folder):
  for file in files:
    filename = os.path.join(path, file)
    folder_size += os.path.getsize(filename)

print "Folder = %0.1f MB" % (folder_size/(1024*1024.0))
```

Comment: What makes this version faster than the program shown in the question?